# Ошибка при генерации yml файла

Tags: php, yml

[image: Ошибка при генерации yml файла]

Здравствуйте! При генерации yml файла для Яндекс.Маркет выходит такая ошибка. Генерация происходит с помощью php файла, данные беруться из БД. Изначально ругался на амперсанд, я дописал проверку на запрещённые в yml символы согласно [требованиям Яндекса](https://yandex.ru/support/partnermarket/export/yml.html). А теперь я не понимаю где закралась ошибка

Comment: `Server iRU Rock SMB&SOHO` не здесь ли амперсанд стоит?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524908/how-to-escape-in-xml/12524924 возможно это поможет

Comment: @Arendach, спасибо, вы натолкнули меня на нахождение ошибки. Исправил и добавил ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Server iRU Rock SMB&SOHO не здесь ли амперсанд стоит? – Arendach

@Arendach, спасибо, что обратили моё внимание на этот знак. В коде проверки на недопустимые символы стояла лишняя ";". Убрал. Теперь файл генерируется нормально.